# Hypergeometric distribution is a complete family of distributions

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

I am trying to determine if the Hypergeometric Distribution is a complete family of distributions.

The problem states that we have an urn with $m$(a known value) white balls  and $\theta$(unknown value) black balls. Sample $m$ from the urn without replacement. Let $X$ be the number of white balls sampled from the $m$ pulled from the urn.

Given the information it sounds to me like this is a hypergeometric distribution with the pdf:

$$f(X;\theta,m,m)=\frac{{m \choose x}{\theta \choose m-x}}{{m+\theta \choose m}}$$

To show if complete will show equality to zero of the equation below implies $T=0$:

$$\sum_{t=0}^{m}T(t)\frac{{m \choose t}{\theta \choose m-t}}{{m+\theta \choose m}}=0$$

equivalently:

$$\sum_{t=0}^{m}T(t){m \choose t}{\theta \choose m-t}=0$$

Note: 
$${m \choose t}{\theta \choose m-t}>0; \forall t\in\{0,1,2...,m\}$$

Cannot figure out a $T$ that does not equal to zero that will make this true. Am I correct in concluding that $T=0$ and hence the hypergeometric is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that the coefficients are positive doesn’t tell us anything, since $T(t)$ could be negative.

The binomial coefficients $\binom\theta{m-t}$ are polynomials of degree $m-t$ in $\theta$. The polynomial resulting from the sum must be identically $0$, so the coefficient of every power of $\theta$ must be zero. The only term of degree $m$ is the one with $T(0)$, so $T(0)=0$. Then the only remaining term of degree $m-1$ is the one with $T(1)$, so $T(1)=0$. And so on.

Comment: The binomial coefficients ${θ \choose m−t}$ are polynomials of degree $m−t$ in $\theta$. I have never seen a binomial coefficient being a polynomial. Can you refer me to some material that can elaborate on this material?

Comment: @NoeVidales: This is just the definition of the binomial coefficient:

$$
\binom\theta n=\frac{\theta(\theta-1)\cdots(\theta-n+1)}{n!}\;,
$$

which is a polynomial of degree $n$ in $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you, The $\theta$ is unknown so we can treat it as a variable.

Comment: @NoeVidales: Yes. In this context, "in $\theta$" means "with $\theta$ as a variable".